# Cannot connect to remote host in pycharm

Tags: ssh, pycharm

I just can't connect to remote interpreter in Pycharm professional on my Mac. But I've connected to my interpreter very well in the past few weeks.

It is always showing "Connecting to XXX(my host ip)". I configured it with SSH Credentials and Deployment configuration. And I tested the sftp, it worked fine.

However, I can use my terminal to connect to my host successfully via ssh.
I just don't understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways and finally found that it was because I changed the default bash to zsh on my server. After changing zsh back to bash, it was fixed.